# Checking if the array has, for example, three values

Tags: php, arrays

How would I check if an array(with three values)  that was passed to a function from another file has all three values? 
For example I want to get an error if someone puts in $ids=Api_Books_Book::getTest(array(1,2,)); (There is no value on the the third key/index).

this is my code so far

```
public static function getTest($ids){
        $input_result = array(
                      );

        foreach ($ids as $id) {
       $input_result['result']['Id '.$id] =  $id;
       }

            if((array_key_exists('0',$ids))){

            echo "You have inputted some data in the Api_Books_Book::getTest<br/>";
            $input_success = "Successful!";
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "There is no data<br/>";
            $input_success = "Not Successful";
        }

        $result=array('status'=>$input_success,
                      'message'=>"some errors will be displayed here",
                      'result'=> $input_result
                     );



        rdie($result);



                return $result;
}
```

Comment: How about `if (count($ids) != 3)`?

Comment: what about when a array has more then 3? for example...someone entered 5 values?

Comment: What about it? What do you want the behaviour to be?

Comment: I want it to check all three/four/five/...../ values. Don't wanna for to be fixed...it depends on the given array...if it has 6 values...great...if 1....same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have simple numerically indexed arrays, the only thing that makes sense is `count`:

```
if (count($array) != 3) // not valid
```

or:

```
if (count($array) < 3) // not valid
```

You can use `$array = array_values($array)` to reset the numeric keys to make sure the values are at index `[0]`, `[1]` and `[2]` and not any other indexes.

If you have key => value pairs and you expect certain keys to be set, use [`array_diff_key`](http://php.net/array_diff_key):

```
$expectedKeys = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
if (array_diff_key(array_flip($expectedKeys), $array)) // not valid
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out a noob. We are depending on you high skilled programmers type. :-D